# ListView is reloaded when switch between tabs. How to stop it?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have Created two tabs using tabhost and added the Fragments using `addTab` method.

In these two fragments, i am simply calling a simple local service using ASYNCTASK and receiving a json of string.

I parse these string values in a listview in both the Fragments.

Now when i switch between fragment tabs, service is called again and list is created again obviously because the fragment gets destroyed when switched between.

Is there a way to retain the fragment tab state and listview state too when switching between tabs ?

Comment: You should add the code you use to generate your ListView

Comment: Keep your adapters in your activity - rather than the fragment that gets destroyed...then use getter methods to set the adapter when you rebuild your fragment's listview.

Comment: i've met this issue once ..  Finally i'm just recreating the list items .. i mean recreate all the items in listview

Comment: It is a simple listadapter taking the input of a string array. It's not much of a code to put. I am sure there is no error in code. I am just having trouble of saving tabs state.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [Fragment.onActivityCreated(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29) to save and restore your fragments?

You could consider using `setRetainInstance(true)` also as mentioned in the doc.

Comment: Not very sure if this would help in your case.

Comment: Not Helpful... I am not a noob. I have tried quite much. I just hope Android is like iOS Coding. Everything is handled there. Saving state is such a pain

Comment: Okay! Another thought...mabbe you have tried this too already. :) try using FragmentTransaction.show() and hide() methods.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to do this and if you find a solution, then please post the answer. Thanks

Comment: Oh! I am sorry for that. I have had myself tried couple of implementations including the one suggested above except that I had implemented them for navigationdrawer and not particularly tabs. Since, I thought they may be relevant here, I decided to post them.

Comment: Please post the relevant code for navigation drawer. I will take a look at it. It might be useful